# How to add URL with # to performance test in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, single-page-application, performance-testing

The URL with # (f.e. http://localhost/#/login) is not allowed in 'Properties' window while adding new request in the performance test. How can I test my single page application with # in URLs?

[image]

Comment: Can you try with %23 instead of # Hash.

Comment: I've just tried http://localhost/%23/login/ and it's allowed for URL but doesn't work for me, I got 404

Comment: Have you added content encoding header?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I added utf-8 encoding, error message is 404, not found

Comment: Try with this `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1` please

Comment: There is still no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142012/discussion-between-naveenkumar-namachivayam-and-julia-savinkova).